# 2 regular graphs and permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78885/on-a-formula-that-relates-2-regular-graphs-on-n-vertices-and-permutations-of/78892) on MSE before but I didn't find the answer satisfactory and it is so old I doubt anyone is still following it.

Let $f_{n}$ be the number of permutations on $[n]$ with no fixed points or two cycles. Let $g_{n}$ be the number of simple, labeled two regular graphs on $n$ vertices. Let $F(x)$ be the EGF for $f_{n}$ and $G(x)$ be the EGF for $g_{n}$. I've shown that $F(x)=G(x)^{2}$. So by composition of exponential genereating functions

$$f_{n}=\sum_{k\geq 0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}g_{k}g_{n-k}$$.

I am tasked to prove $F(x)=G(x)^{2}$ via a bijective proof. I know that given a graph on $k$ vertices we can decompose it into cycles. Then for each cycle we can orient the cycle two ways to make a permutation on $n$. But I think this count is too large.

Any hint would help thanks.

Comment: Please give a link to the earlier Question on MSE, and if possible, be a little more explicit about what makes the Answer(s) there unsatisfactory.  You obviously have some good insights about the problem, and the goal is to make the site as useful as possible for future Readers (such as yourself in this case).

Comment: @hardmath: I’ve added a link to the earlier question. The answer is unsatisfactory because it’s wrong; I’ve added a comment to that effect under it, together with a brief explanation of the error and a link to this question. The author hasn’t been around for the last week and a half, but I expect that he’ll see it eventually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Each permutation of $[n]$ with no fixed points and no $2$-cycles corresponds in an obvious way to a unique labelled two-regular directed graph in which each cyclic component is a directed cycle. Given such a graph $G$, we can split the components into two sets, $\mathscr{C}_I(G)$ and $\mathscr{C}_D(G)$, as follows:

> Suppose that $C$ is a component whose lowest-numbered vertex is $v$; there are vertices $u$ and $w$ in $C$ such that $u\to v$ and $v\to w$ are directed edges of $C$. If $u<w$, put $C$ into $\mathscr{C}_I(G)$, and if $u>w$, put $C$ into $\mathscr{C}_D(G)$.

Let $G_I=\bigcup\mathscr{C}_I$ and $G_D=\bigcup\mathscr{C}_D$. Now show that for a fixed set of $k$ labels from $[n]$ there are $g_k$ possible graphs $G_I$ and $g_{n-k}$ possible graphs $G_D$.

Comment: For the last comment you mean. Given a fixed set of labels $k$ from $[n]$ we can make $g_{k}$ graphs from the directed components of $G_{I}$?

Comment: @TheNumber23: No, I mean that if $K$ is a $k$-subset of $[n]$, there are $g_k$ possible graphs $G_I$.

Comment: Ok, I must be misunderstanding the meaning of $G_{I}$. Are we taking the union over all directed labelled two regular graphs? Therefore $G_{I}$ would no longer be a directed two-regular graph.

Comment: @TheNumber23: For a fixed set $K$ of labels, each possible $G_I$ is a directed labelled two-regular graph on the vertex set $K$. However, the way that I defined $\mathscr{C}_I(G)$ and $\mathscr{C}_D(G)$ ensures that for any undirected labelled two-regular graph on $K$ there is only one way to direct the edges that is possible for a $G_I$ on $K$.

Comment: Yes, for each $G$, $\mathscr{C}_I(G)$ has only one direction and each component is vertex disjoint. But when we sum up over all $G$ can't we get some overlapping components?

Comment: @TheNumber23: I honestly don’t understand what you mean. It’s certainly possible that a component of one graph on $[n]$ overlaps several components of another, but that has nothing to do with the way that I’m counting.

Comment: I completely misunderstood what you meant by $G_{I}$ but I figured it out. The hint was exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @TheNumber23: You’re welcome. I’m glad that you asked the question: that was fun, and it’s nice to have a correction to the old answer, too.